# JavaScript - If statement within an For Statement

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, when I remove the if statement and just work with the `text += "The first car is " + cars[i] + "<br>";` it works just fine (aside from the obvious grammar problems.

Could someone have a look at the code below and explain why it doesn't work?

`

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var cars = ["BMW", "Audi", "Tesla", "Ferrari", "Mini"];

for (text = "", l = cars.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if(i = 0){
        text += "The first car is " + cars[i] + "<br>";
    } else if (i < l - 1) {
            text += text + "The next car is " + cars[i] + "<br>";   
    } else {
            text += text + "The final car is " + cars[i] + "<br>";  
    }
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Many thanks
Maudise

Comment: `if(i === 0){` instead of `if(i=0){`

Comment: Perfect, really simple fix.  Many thanks. Maudise

Answer (score 2):

You should write `==`

```
if(i == 0)
```

`=` is for assigning a value to a variable.

`==` means "is equal to" and is used for comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what you're trying to do, but `if(i = 0)` is usually a mistake - that line sets `i` to 0, then checks if it's nonzero.  To check the value of `i` without changing its value, use `==`:

```
for (text = "", l = cars.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if(i == 0){
        text += "The first car is " + cars[i] + "<br>";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `if(i = 0)`.

A single `=` is an **assignment operator**.

You want to use a **comparison operator**, such as `==` or `===`.

Some people who have answered have suggested `==`. However, I would recommend using the **strict comparison operator**: `===`.

```
if(i === 0)
```

---

### Extra information not really pertinent to the question

In the code you've given, it wouldn't really matter whether you used the strict operator or not; however, it is good to understand why you would or wouldn't want to use it.

For example:

```
0 == false // ==> true
0 === false // ==> false
```

The `==` comparison operator looks for "falsy" and "truthy" values. In other words, some values like `undefined`, `0`, `null`, etc., are all "falsy", and will return `false` when using `==`.

Comment: I think most people recommend `==` because it's more language-agnostic.  The `=` vs. `==` mistake first became well-known in C, which doesn't even have an `===` operator, and most corrections still follow that language's pattern.  I agree that `===` is slightly better in the languages that have it (such as javaScript and PHP), though.